# LSZ Reduction Formula (Weinberg Derivation)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, fourier-transform, s-matrix-theory

In section 10.3 of Weinberg's Volume 1 in deriving LSZ reduction Formula, the author says,

> We also define a 'truncated' matrix element $M_l$ by
> $$\int d^4 x_2 \cdots e^{-q_2x_2} <\textbf q \sigma| T\{A(x_2)\cdots\}\Omega> = N^{-1} (2\pi)^{-3/2} \sum_l u_l(\textbf q, \sigma) M_l(q_2,\cdots).\tag{10.3.4}$$

Here $ u_l(\textbf q, \sigma)$ is the coefficient function of the annihilation operator of a  free field. Such definition of $M_l$ presupposes the isolation of $\textbf q, \sigma $ contribution from the other variables. Therefore, I was asking how we are allowed to make such definitions.